# Combinatorics Question about Positive Odd Numbers

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways are there to add four positive odd numbers to get a sum
>   of $22$?

The answer is 18. However, I am weak in this topic so I am not sure of the solution for this question. Can anyone help? Thanks :D!

Comment: Hint: The number of ways to add four positive odd numbers to get a sum of 22 is the same as the number of ways to add three positive odd numbers to get a sum less than 22.

Comment: I know how to do it manually but I am not sure about how to solve it using Permutations and Combinations.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Every positive odd number $x$ can be written in the form $x=2n-1$, where $n$ is some positive integer, and so if the sum of four odd numbers $a=2i-1,b=2j-1,c=2k-1,d=2l-1$ is $22$, then:

$$a+b+c+d=22\\
\implies 2(i+j+k+l)-4=22\\
\implies 2(i+j+k+l)=26\\
\implies i+j+k+l=13.$$

Hence, the number of ways to add four odd numbers to 22 is equal to the number of ways to add four numbers to 13, or in other words, the number of partitions of $13$ into $4$ parts.

Comment: I agree with this solution if we are assuming the order of the summands does not matter.  Otherwise I would say there are 220 ways.